# waiting for code.jquery.com... Firefox

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm building a web app off a local wampserver and the site runs blazingly fast. Except every now and then, Firefox hangs up with the following message:

`waiting for http://code.jquery.com...`

HttpFox shows me that code.jquery.com is taking 10 seconds to load in jquery!

Any idea why code.jquery.com hangs like this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out code.jquery.com just 301 redirects to google. I switched my javascript includes to the googleapis equivalent and hello performance.

http://www.webperformancematters.com/journal/2009/8/21/jquery-library-performance-alert.html